# Correct way to implement inheritance in C#

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

The following example works fine, but it has a flaw: the `Square` object has the `Width` and `Height` properties of the `Rectangle`. A good implementation of the `Square` object won't provide these properties to the user:

```
public class Rectangle
{
    public double Width { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }
    public double Area { get { return Width * Height; } }
}

public class Square : Rectangle
{
    public double Side
    {
        get { return Width; }
        set { Width = Height = value; }
    }
}
```

I thought of a few ways to fix that (including new properties and the `Obsolete` tag). The best solution was to cancel the inheritance, and instead keep a `Rectangle` as a private variable of the `Square` object. This would work, but will require re-writing the `Rectangle` methods for `Square`, which is against the whole purpose of OOP. Please help me understand what is the right way to implement this.

Thanks

Comment: Just have the properties be `private set` and pass the width and height as constructor arguments?

Comment: Why shouldn't a `Square` have a width or a height property? A square is just a rectangle where the width and height are the same.

Comment: You've correctly identified that a `Square` doesn't implement the interface for `Rectangle`.  A rectangle can have non-equal width/height, but a square requires that width/height be equal.  There isn't a inheritance relationship here, so the right way to do this would be not to use inheritance.

Comment: Uh, no.  Squares have a width and a height.  You just override `Rectangle`s implementation of them to force them to be the same.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/238176/why-would-square-inheriting-from-rectangle-be-problematic-if-we-override-the-set

Comment: A square is a rectangle where setting width also sets height and vice versa. The side property can set both.

Comment: There is no good clear answer for this. This problem is well known https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem Please read the wiki, this question can't be clearly answered and I am voting to close it.

Comment: I'm with @Amy.  Mathematically, a square is a type of rectangle.  But to try to force that into OOP is going to violate the Liskov Principal of SOLID

Comment: See also the great Eric Lippert:  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2012/02/13/bad-metaphors/

Comment: It would depend on the applications we want to do with the square and rectangle. There's no clear answer - it is too broad

Comment: In addition to @Amy comment i think you can make a shape abstract class or interface and inhert from it for all of you shapes have the Area

Comment: I think squares and rectangles are bad examples for OOP. While it's true to say squares and rectangles could be derived from a class called `Shape`. I don't think deriving square from rectangle is particularly helpful. It strikes me to perhaps think of a square as a special case of rectangle (like how an equilateral triangle is a special case of triangle) rather than derived from a rectangle. So perhaps a `Rectangle` class with a constructor that takes 1 argument (in addition to a 2 arg) that would give you a `Rectangle` with equal height and width (i.e. a square) and a `IsSquare` property?

Comment: No the issue here isn't that Squares aren't really derived from Rectangles (they are) nor that they aren't a type of Rectangle (they are), but rather that what is being modeled in OOP here isn't truly Squares and Rectangles, but rather *mutable* Squares and Rectangles.  And technically a *mutable Square* is not truly a "type of", nor derived from a *mutable Rectangle* because it cannot accept all of the same transformations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't agree that `Square` shouldn't provide `Width` and `Height` properties since squares absolutely do have a width and height just like any rectangle. The only difference is that they are necessarily the same.

The way I'd fix it, is to either make a `Rectangle` immutable, or allow `Square` to override the properties:

```
public class Rectangle
{
    public virtual int Width { get; set; }
    public virtual int Height { get; set; }

    public Rectangle(int width, int height)
    {
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
    }
}

public class Square : Rectangle
{
    public override int Width
    {
        get { return Side; }
        set { Side = value; }
    }

    public override int Height
    {
        get { return Side; }
        set { Side = value; }
    }

    public int Side { get; set; }

    public Square(int side)
        : base(side, side)
    {
        Side = side;
    }
}
```

Comment: No need for separate variables for `_height` and `_width`, they are the same value, see the answer by @nvoigt

Comment: @DavidG That's a good point. I was just using it to reinforce the point. I'll update my answer though.

Answer (score 2):

That's a common problem that some people answer with "OOP is not the silver bullet". But if you really want to use OOP mechanisms here, you could override the Width to always be the Height for a square. So if you set one, the other changes as well. Not perfect, but it works.

```
public class Rectangle
{
    public virtual double Width { get; set; }
    public virtual double Height { get; set; }
    public double Area { get { return Width * Height; } }
}

public class Square : Rectangle
{
    public override double Width { get { return Height; } set { Height = value; } }
}
```

Comment: I would say the answer is "Inheritance is not the silver bullet". You should design your classes so that Square and Rectangle should not inherit from each other.

Answer (score 2):

Don't inherit `Square` from `Rectangle`. You are trying to have the relation between your abstractions same as the relation between objects which they represent. But think about following

> When the spouses are getting divorced each one of them has the lawyer which represents them. It's very unlikely that those two lawyers themselves are getting divorced. *Because the representatives of things do not share the relationships of things they represent* © Uncle Bob

Your `Square` class represents square geometric shape. But it's not a geometric shape. It's a code. Same with `Rectangle` class. And relationship between geometric shapes are not shared by these representatives. Let's talk about problems which you will have if you will try to share relationship between geometric square and rectangle with `Square` and `Rectangle` classes in your code.

If you inherit `Square` from `Rectangle` then you can treat any square as base class:

```
var rectangle = new Square { Side = 10 };
rectangle.Width = 20;
```

Now you have 'square' object with width 20 and height 10. Did you expect to have such square? OK, you can synchronize those properties. I.e. when you change width, height will change as well and vice versa:

```
rectangle.Width = 5;
rectangle.Height = 10;
Assert.That(rectangle.Area, Is.EqualTo(50)); // wtf it fails?
```

Did you expect that height also will be 5 if you are using variable of base type (rectangle)? It's not valid behavior of rectangle. And it violates [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwhCYaYDn8EgNzAzZjA5ZmItNjU3NS00MzQ5LTkwYjMtMDJhNDU5ZTM0MTlh/view).

If you will not inherit `Square` from `Rectangle` - none of those problems will appear. Square will have single property `Side` and it will behave as you expect. The only case when you might inherit `Square` from `Rectangle` without having unexpected values of width or height - if make those object immutable. But another problem will stay - your square still will have properties `Width` and `Height` which are confusing. It should have only one property `Side`.

Comment: That seems a particularly specious use of the word  _"represent"_ - a very poor use of homonyms. In your example the lawyer "representing" the wife could very well be male - it does not mean the wife is a man - in that situation "represent" means "appointed to act on behalf of" rather than "constitutes or amounts to".

Comment: @PaulF that seems like you are extremely good in English. I have added source of the the quote.

Comment: I did assume that you were quoting somebody else, so my apologies if I came across as getting at you. But I think it is a very poor example and also very confusing - just based on the dual meanings (in English) of the word "represent". Confusing the meanings of homonyms can be very effective in jokes - but is not useful in technical discussions regardless of the source.

Comment: I would have expected "Uncle Bob" to have been able to make the distinction between the two meaningss clear rather than conflating them for his own argument.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the Rectangle properties to `virtual` will allow you to override their behaviors and have square inherit Rectangle.
Please see the example below for more information:

```
public class Rectangle
{
    public virtual double Width { get; set; }
    public virtual double Height { get; set; }
    public double Area { get { return Width * Height; } }
}

public class Square : Rectangle
{
    public double Side { get; set; }

    public override double Height
    {
        get { return Side; }
        set { Side = value; }
    }

    public override double Width
    {
        get { return Side; }
        set { Side = value; }
    }
}
```